# Web API call not reaching?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

i am using route prefix in my api

```
[RoutePrefix("api/currencies")]
public class DefCurrencyController : ApiController
  {
   [HttpGet, Route("")]
   public List<DefCurrency> GetAllCurrencies()
    {
        return DefCurrency.AllDefCurrency;
    }
}
```

my webapi config file

```
 namespace ERPServices
  {
    public static class WebApiConfig
   {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        //    name: "DefaultApi",
        //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        //);
      }
   }
}
```

i am trying to reach or acess the `GetAllCurrencies()` using

```
http://localhost:1865/api/currencies
```

it returns error

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

what should i do to test my controller api ?

Answer (score 2):

Ditch the `RoutePrefix` attribute on the controller and just declare the route you want on the method:

```
public class DefCurrencyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("api/currencies")]
    public List<DefCurrency> GetAllCurrencies()
    {
        return DefCurrency.AllDefCurrency;
    }
}
```

Route prefix is for where you want to declare a portion of the route to apply to all methods in the controller (e.g. they are in an area).

Also, you don't need `HttpPost` here, this should be GET only.

You should also check that in your `WebApiConfig` you are calling `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` before any convention based routing.

Comment: SEE ABOVE EDITTING IN QUESTION BUT STILL NOT RESOLVED

Answer (score 1):

Please try below of test the API

http://localhost:1865/api/currencies/GetAllCurrencies

Comment: you cannot call using function name when route attribute is used

Answer (score 1):

There are several things required to make WebAPI work.

Add this is you project:

```
using System.Web.Http;

    namespace WebConfig
    {
        public static class WebApiConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            }
        }
    }
```

And in your `Global.asax` file, add this in the `Application_Start` to call the `Register` method:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Also, in the web service, try changing for the following values to test the routing:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class DefCurrencyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("currencies")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
       return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: call not reaching still

Comment: SEE ABOVE EDITTING IN QUESTION BUT STILL NOT RESOLVED

Comment: Have you tried the code like I have it?? I have both RoutePrefix and Route; that's what I use in my own code and it works. Also, for testing purpose, I recommend you set up a client call using jquery ajax, just to test and get it working. And also remove the actual implementation with currencies for now, just return a string "it works" to start with.